# Not able to get the list of azure repository using python

Tags: azure-container-registry

I’m newbie to azure, trying to list the repositories in azure container registry using client id, tenant id, secret using below code.

```
from azure.containerregistry import ContainerRegistryClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential


registry_name = "test1"
resource_group = "donieee"
app_id="xxxxx"
secret="xxxxxxx"
tenantid="xxxxxx"

credential = ClientSecretCredential(client_id=app_id,client_secret=secret,tenant_id=tenantid)

# Create a client object for the ACR
client = ContainerRegistryClient(
    endpoint=f"{registry_name}.azurecr.io",
    credential=credential
)

repositories = client.list_repository_names()
for repo in repositories:
    print(repo)
```

getting below error
azure.core.exceptions.ClientAuthenticationError: Operation returned an invalid status ‘Unauthorised’

Kindly suggest me answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got the same error:**

[image]

The above error occurs when your application doesn't have the proper role to list the repositories.

> **Note:**  According to [**MS-DOCS**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-roles?tabs=azure-cli)  to list the respositories you need either **`ACR pull`** role or **`Contributor`** role required.

On my side, I have assigned the role to the application and run the same code it is listing the repositories.

**Code:**

```
from azure.containerregistry import ContainerRegistryClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential


registry_name = "test1"
resource_group = "donieee"
app_id="xxxxx"
secret="xxxxxxx"
tenantid="xxxxxx"

credential = ClientSecretCredential(client_id=app_id,client_secret=secret,tenant_id=tenantid)

# Create a client object for the ACR
client = ContainerRegistryClient(
    endpoint=f"{registry_name}.azurecr.io",
    credential=credential
)

repositories = client.list_repository_names()
for repo in repositories:
    print(repo)
```

In my portal, I have some repositories in my Azure container registry like as below.

**Portal:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Venkatesan after assigning role it worked.